# How to turn off TexStudio forcing text on you while typing?

Tags: latex

When typing code like `\(` or `\begin{equation}` TexStudio is hijacking my document inserting closing `\)` and adding red boxes its expecting me to type inside of to somehow make go away, and it's slowing me down and interfering with what I wish to type. How do I disable this "helpful" feature?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the top bar, click *Options > Configure TeXstudio*.  Then select `Show Advanced Options` in the lower left.  Then select `Adv Editor` in the left pane.  Then unselect `Auto Completion Parentheses`.

[image]

**EDIT:**

I believe that you are looking to turn off the Auto Completer which puts in the words.  In the left pane, click on `Completion`.  Then unselect `Automatically start completer when typing LaTeX-Commands`.

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. What does unchecking "Overwrite [...] Placeholder" accomplish? The expected behavior of typing over the outlined braces inserted by TexStudio did not change. Additionally, `\begin{equation}` etc. still inserts additional text and I don't see the option to disable it here, but maybe this feature is more acceptable ... It would be good if you would add how to disable this feature as well.

Comment: @DBinJP Added in answer for disabling the completer, which is what I think you are looking for.

Comment: The edit is absolutely what I was looking for. Now the editor doesn't bog down my typing and freeze up as it searches for completions. Just writing something as simple as $1 \leq i \leq n$ makes it freeze up and query commands that complete "\l". Ridiculous.